# Calculating algorithm time

Tags: c#, .net, performance, algorithm, time

I have an algorithm that works with extremely large numbers around the order of 2 raised to the power 4,500,000. I use the BigInteger class in .NET 4 to handle these numbers.

The algorithm is very simple in that it is a single loop that reduces a large initial number based on some predefined criteria. With each iteration, the number is reduced by around 10 exponents so 4,500,000 would become 4,499,990 in the next iteration.

I am currently getting 5.16 iterations per second or 0.193798 seconds per iteration. Based on that the total time for the algorithm should be roughly 22 hours to bring the exponent value down to 0.

The problem is, as the number is reduced, the time required to process the number in memory is reduced as well. Plus, as the exponent reduces to the 200,000 range, the iterations per second become huge and the reduction per iteration also increases exponentially.

Instead of letting the algo run for a whole day, is there a mathematical way to calculate how much time it would take based on an initial starting number and iterations per second?

This would be very helpful since I can measure improvements of optimization attempts quickly.

Consider the following psuedocode:

```
double e = 4500000; // 4,500,000.
Random r = new Random();
while (e > 0)
{
    BigInteger b = BigInteger.Power(2, e);
    double log = BigInteger.Log(b, 10);
    e -= Math.Abs(log * r.Next(1, 10));
}
```

Comment: is e being incremented?

Comment: @thang: If I start off with an exponent value of 200,000, the algorithm would only take a few seconds to process. The algorithm is of course much more complex but the above code would yield the same results since the majority time per iteration is comsumed by the BigInteger constructor. So you can imagine it would speed up substantially as the number reduces.

Comment: @CR41G14: My mistake. Fixed the code. `e` is being reduced in each iteration.

Comment: @thang: I'm not sure how you got that impression. Please point me to it so I can update the question. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried measuring and interpolating the time it takes per iteration as a function of e?

Comment: @thang: No I had not thought of that. How would you do that? Let the algo run fully once, map the e and ips values and use that graph for future estimates?

Comment: you don't need to run it through entirely.  just take like the first N iterations -- say 10 iterations, which would be like 2 seconds.  use that data to extrapolate forward.  maybe it (time per iteration) would look like an exponentially decaying function... then you can fit an b exp(-a t) through the data.  that will let you extrapolate forward in time without having to run the entire thing for  a day.

Comment: You can calculate a bestcase and worstcase Szenario maybe? With the original Algorithm you would be able to do a full runtime-analyses. See this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big-omega_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Comment: Why are you using `BigInteger.Log` over a simple multiplication of `e`?

Comment: i suspect he just wants to swap base and doesn't know that log(2^e) = e log(2)

Comment: @CodesInChaos: The example does not have any actual logic. It only demonstrates the presence of Power and Log functions and the fact that e is being reduced.

Comment: @thang: You should post this as an answer so I can accept. Thanks.

Comment: " With each iteration, the number is reduced by around 10 exponents so 4,500,000 would become 4,499,990 in the next iteration." That does not match your pseudo-code at all. Your pseudo code has a ~70% chance of setting e to a negative value on each iteration.

Comment: You do know that you do not need BigInteger at all to do this, right?  The first two lines of your loop can be replaced with a simple multiplication by a constant, without ever going to BigInteger.

Comment: Oh, and `e` is a really bad choice of variable names for an algorithm like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rewrite

```
double log = BigInteger.Log(b, 10);
```

as

```
double log = log(2)/log(10) * e; // approx 0.3 * e
```

Then you notice that the algorithm terminates after O(1) iterations (~70% termination chance on each iteration), you can probably neglect the cost of everything apart from the first iteration.

The total cost of your algo is about 1 to 2 times as expensive as `Math.Pow(2, e)` for the initial exponent `e`. For base=2 this is a trivial bitshift, for others you'll need square-and-multiply

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try to see if it approximates the actual time close enough.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to estimate the time of the unknown since you are using Random!

Comment: Actually Random is only used in the code example to limit the reduction to between 1 and 10 per iteration. I would happy to use that level of approximation.

Comment: If you say each iteration is going to change dramatically due to the values then no I don't think this is possible, the only thing you can do is get an elapsed time per 1000 iterations and use that as a guestimate.